# jfxmobile-plugin apk generation fails for double visit of a single jar

Tags: android, javafxports

My javafxport android project (gradle project) fails due to some weird duplicate file exception. The reason for this exception occurs is clear to me: Every library my project depends on (either my own developed libraries or 3rd party libraries like jfoenix.jar) is visited twice by the jfxmobile-plugin since the exception indicates that a file, say X, is found in two different jar files which in fact are the same single artifact.

Here is a more detailed description:

```
jfxmobile-plugin version : org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.0
```

Sample dependency from build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    androidCompile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:1.0.0'
}
```

Creating api using this command:

```
gradle androidInstall
```

results in:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mylib-android-demo-dist:apkDebug'.
> com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException:
Duplicate files copied in APK resources/font/roboto/Apache License.txt
File 1: C:\Users\Amin\.m2\repository\com\jfoenix\jfoenix\1.0.0\jfoenix-1.0.0.jar
File 2: C:\Users\Amin\.m2\repository\com\jfoenix\jfoenix\1.0.0\jfoenix-1.0.0.jar
```

Can anyone guess what's happening here?

Here is real build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

mainClassName = 'com.mycompany.MainClass'

dependencies {
    compile ('com.mycompany:mylib-android-demo-predist:1.1-SNAPSHOT')
    {
        exclude module: 'stax-api'
    }
    androidCompile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-5'
    androidCompile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-5') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }
    androidCompile 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:1.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
}
```

Note that I've integrated all the other dependencies into a single jar file using maven dependency plugin.

Very important:
The same issue is with jfxrt.jar file; there is a file 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST' which is printed out as a duplicate file by the grandle androidInstall task.
This jfxrt.jar file is not a declared dependency by any of my own libraries but is a javafx runtime for android which comes from javafxports project by the gradle plugin (jfxmobile-plugin) itself.

Comment: Can you post the full list of dependencies?

Comment: In fact, I unpacked and integrated all the other dependencies into a single jar file using maven dependency plugin's goal named 'unpack'. as far as I can see the jfoenix.jar 's classes are also there and this might be the reason for the mentioned duplicate conflict.  However, I can't understand why both File 1 and File 2 point to the same jar file.

Comment: There is yet another transitive dependency which is auto-added by jfxmobile-plugin. This jar file named jfxrt.jar  (javafx runtime) and is not declared in none of my own library projects but brought by the plugin itself. Without jfoenix.jar as a dependency, I've faced the same issue with some resource inside jfxrt.jar which is marked as duplicate file in exactly the same way jfoenix.jar is.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file? Otherwise it is impossible to say what can be happening.

Comment: @JoséPereda thanks. I will post it right now.

Comment: Can you clean your project? Run `gradlew.bat clean android --info`, and check again.

Comment: Sorry for my latency  (It's a fairly large project (a mix of maven and gradle projects) with lots of dependencies;  I'm moving/excluding some dependencies here and then trying to compile and fix issues. Sometime a new issue comes up which takes even more time to fix and come back to this question. Thank you for your seriousness in resolving this issue.

Comment: Also you can run `gradlew.bat dependencies`, that will show you all the dependencies (check the androidCompile or androidRuntime ones) and you might spot duplicates.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':xray-android-demo-dist:apkDebug'.
> com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/INDEX.LIST
 File 1: C:\Users\Amin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javafxports\dalvik-sdk\8.60.8\6630ec66e4703c910ac3fd6151a8494c8b59186b\unpacked\dalvik-sdk\rt\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar
 File 2: C:\Users\Amin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.javafxports\dalvik-sdk\8.60.8\6630ec66e4703c910ac3fd6151a8494c8b59186b\unpacked\dalvik-sdk\rt\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar

Comment: Above you see the same resource issue with jfxrt.jar which I reproduced. What would be the reason for such a disaster?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131155/discussion-between-jose-pereda-and-amin).

Comment: There is a bug in the android gradle tools library. It prints the same file for File 1 and File 2. You will need to declare packagingOptions to either only include the duplicated file once or exclude it completely. http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_packagingoptions

Comment: @JoeriSykora are you sure it is a bug?! I do not use packagingOptions since there are lots of resources there to declare one by one.  Note that the main cause of this issue is that the same jar file is visited twice. So, I should force the plugin to exclude every single resource in every single jar file since it is going to be detected as duplicate for sure.

Anyway, Is there any option to say 'Please override all the duplicates anywhere'

Comment: @Amin Yes, I'm 100% sure. The jfxmobile-plugin depends on an older version of the android gradle tools (1.1.3 to be precise). Here's the specific code that shows the bug: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_1.1.3/build-system/builder/src/main/java/com/android/builder/packaging/DuplicateFileException.java#59

Comment: @JoeriSykora thank you very much. Your hint helped me solve my problem. Before that I was just wondering why the two names are exactly the same and this prevented me from further investigation around the actual cause of the exception.

Comment: @Amin, you are welcome. I'm glad I could direct you to finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem you are facing is a very common one with Gradle / Android. The Problem is, that a (license) file with the same name was already copied to the target location from another JAR file. To solve this, please refer to the Gradle `packagingOptions` either on `JavaFXPorts`' [documentation under the Android section](http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_android_4) or have a look at the `Gradle` [documentation on GitHub](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html). (I'd prefer not to exclude the licences altogether, but pick the first one encountered ( `pickFirst` ).

I'm currently developing an `JavaFXPorts` application as well and needed to do this, too...